# Two computer share load

Tags: windows-server-2008, mysql, tomcat

I have two windows server 2008, name as computer A and computer B. I intend to use computer A as a web and database server and computer B as a web server. I'm using apache tomcat and mysql database. How can I set the web request to be distributed? The clients are mobile phones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find Windows Network Load Balancing to be a simple, if very basic, way to implement this

Answer (score 0):

You should probably read up on the concept of load balancing, for instance from this presentation http://www.slideshare.net/bradley.holt/load-balancing-with-apache

The actual implementation will depend a bit on how you application looks; when I worked with mobile web; back when it was called wap - the fact that there were mobiles and not computers on the other end had much less bearing than what we were doing in the backend.